# Broken PDF when forcedownloaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdf, blob

I'm using an API call (cURL, server-side) to receive an XML file. The XML file has a base64 encoded PDF embedded within, and I'm extracting this file from the XML, and then saving it on the server for later downloading.

I'm doing it like this:

```
<?php

$pdfContents = $content["DocumentHeader"]["DocumentPdf"]; // base64 string PDF
$endDocument = base64_decode($pdfContents);
$realName = 'some_random_string.pdf';
$filename = 'adjusted_name.pdf';
file_put_contents($realName,$endDocument);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: application/octetstream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($realName);

unlink($realName);

die();
?>
```

The front-end is receiving the file like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get-file.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    success:function(data,status,xhr) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type:'application/pdf' });
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        window.location.href = downloadUrl;
    }
});
```

While this does download a PDF file, that file is broken. By broken, I mean that the contents are not entirely valid.

See the following image. On the right is the broken file, and on the left is what the file should display, when open in, say, Sublime Text 3 (or any other text editor).

[image: PDF contents comparison]

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the way I'm creating the `Blob`, or (not) processing the `data`, but I'm unsure what.

Here are some of the things I've tried:

1. Changing the `header('Content-type')` to `application/pdf`
2. Removing / commenting out the `header('Content-Transfer-Encoding')`
3. Using the `TextEncoder` and `TextDecoder`
4. Changing the front-end JS handling of `data` to:

```
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataArray[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
}
var blob = new Blob([dataArray], { type:'application/pdf' });
```

You might ask why am I not simply passing the link to the PDF, and simulating a click on a hidden `<a href>`, or why am I not setting the `responseType` to `blob`, or why am I even using AJAX to begin with.

The answer to the first question is twofold - there are multiple simultaneous users (in the hundreds), and I'd like to avoid them knowing the real filename, and also to avoid keeping that file on the server for an indefinite period of time.

The second issue (`responseType`) - my response is not always a PDF file. It might be a JSON, containing a message for the user - the XML was not downloaded, there was an error while retrieving the parameters needed for the XML API call, etc, etc.

The third issue - I want this to work without the need for target blanks and wondering whether the user's browser will block the opening of a new tab, and I also want to keep the user on the page from which they initiated the download etc.

Finally, my question.

What do I need to change in the `Blob` creating part of my code, in order to get a functional PDF? I'm guessing it's an encoding issue, but I'm unsure how to go about fixing it.

---

**EDIT**

I've experimented with the conversion to blob, and after changing it to this:

```
    var byteString = data;
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var intArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        intArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var blob = new Blob([intArray], { type:'application/pdf' });
```

I still get a broken PDF, but with a slightly different encoding issue, like in the following image.

[image: ArrayBuffer conversion]

Comment: You are going to use the same exact request for a pdf and json?

Comment: @Musa No, there's an if / else statement in the JS part (not posted, because it's irrelevant) - if the `data` received is a JSON, I handle it differently. That part works as expected when I trigger some errors server-side, and return the JSON message. The trouble is only in the PDF part of the code.

Comment: What if you take out the AJAX portion of this, and request `get-file.php` directly via your browser address bar - is the content of the PDF that gets saved on your local drive correct in that instance then?

Comment: @CBroe If I do that, the PDF is valid - I can open it without any issues in any randomly chosen PDF viewer. Also, if I open it in a text editor (to view the raw contents of the file), I see what's shown in the first image I posted in my question (left-hand side, marked with VALID PDF). I have also edited my code, for an additional test case (`ArrayBuffer`), and the display I get when I use that (PDF invalid).

Comment: Could it have something to do with this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#parameters: _"Note that strings here are encoded as UTF-8, unlike the usual JavaScript UTF-16 strings."_ If that is the cause of the issue, I suppose you would have to convert your `data` variable in the JS from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

Comment: @KJ You put me on the right track with your comment - `data` which I was receiving was binary and it **was getting garbled** in transport - logging the `xhr.responseText` to the console showed me the diamonds. That made it clear that I **shouldn't** use the streaming of the file, but instead echoing a `base64` version of it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue.

Despite my initial doubts, the problem was indeed **on the server**. Specifically, this part:

```
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    readfile($realName);
```

I was sending the stream, which made it impossible for the front-end logic to convert it correctly to what I needed. The thing that gave it away (apart from the helpful comments) was logging the contents of `xhr.responseText` to the console - instead of the expected format of the PDF contents, I noticed that there were diamonds / improperly converted characters.

With that in mind, I changed my code like this:

```
<?php

$pdfContents = $content["DocumentHeader"]["DocumentPdf"]; // base64 string PDF
//$endDocument = base64_decode($pdfContents);  <== not needed in this case
//$realName = 'some_random_string.pdf';  <== not needed in this case
$filename = 'adjusted_name.pdf';
//file_put_contents($realName,$endDocument); <== not needed in this case

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: application/octetstream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
//header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');   <== not good in this case
//readfile($realName);   <== not good in this case
echo $pdfContents; // <== base64 representation of the raw PDF contents
unlink($realName);

die();
?>
```

Then, in the front-end code, I made additional changes:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get-file.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    success:function(data,status,xhr) {
        //var blob = new Blob([data], { type:'application/pdf' });

        var byteString = atob(data);
        var intArray = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            intArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var blob = new Blob([intArray], { type:'application/pdf' });
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);    
        window.location.href = downloadUrl;
    }
});
```

This forces the download of the received PDF, which looks like expected upon opening.